# license of Microsoft visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

license of Microsoft visual studio 
I want to buy license of Microsoft visual studio  I am a one developer in company and i have multiple users (only browsing) and I will upload my design website on the server of company (intranet) then the end user can access. So now, I want to know how many license must be buy from Microsoft??

can any one help me for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to buy Microsoft Visual Studio License just once. You need to use Visual studio Enterprise.

Comment: thanks for replying

in my company only one developer staff and it is not connect to outside  only LAN(intranet) . So the developer design system and but in server then the users access and read

So I want to buy only standalone (offline) installation VS without help because my company not connect to internet

Regards,

Ahmed